# Get id of the <a> tag from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am very new in javascript/jQuery so please bear with me if my question will be too easy for you and too difficult for me.
This is from a function, I just don't post the complete codes since it will be too long.

And I have another function which also have an ajax and I want to pass get the ID of the `<a>` tag:

```
function someName() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'thisisprivate.aspx',
    data: {
      action: 'MyAction',
      word: 'Wednesday',
      count: '4',
      page: '1'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      var htmlInfo = '';
      for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var htmlCode = '<a href="#/app/video?id=' + json[i].bcid + json[i].name + '" class="list" id="' + json[i].bcid + '"></a>';
        htmlInfo = htmlInfo + htmlCode;
      }

      jQuery('#WMVideoxx').html(htmlInfo);
    }
  });
}
```

and

```
function VideoDiv() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'thisisprivate.aspx',
    data: {
      action: 'actionNameHere',
      idorname: id //I Want to pass the ID here
    });
}
```

Comment: pass the id like `VideoDiv(id)`

Comment: you are generating multiple `a` tags in first ajax call, which one you want to pass in next ajax call?

Comment: See how to pass variables.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar oh yes i forgot to include, i want to pass the ID when the <a> tag is clicked, how do i do that.. sorry i'm really newbie

Comment: @JCBorlagdan You **aren't** calling the function `VideoDiv()` anywhere. Are you calling it actually?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes i'm not but i know how, I just wanna pass the value of the ID in the <a> tag which is i don't know how...

Comment: @JCBorlagdan Fine. I will give you a quicker and also a better way. Answering for you.

Comment: jQuery('a').click(function()
 {
  VideoDiv(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
 }); 

this is what i did, but it's not working coz i don't know the proper way.. Sorry

Comment: @JCBorlagdan you should edit your question and mention the extra information regarding your attempts at solving the problem inside the statement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onclick="function();"` with your anchor and pass arguments that you want in your function

Your htmlcode should be like this

`<a href="#/app/video?id=' + json[i].bcid + json[i].name + '" class="list" id="' + json[i].bcid + '" onclick="VideoDiv('+json[i].bcid+');"></a>`

Your VideoDiv function

```
function VideoDiv(id) 
{
   //your ajax goes here
}
```

Comment: great :) @JCBorlagdan you can pass multiple arguments as well.

Comment: hmm sorry to bring this back, is there a way for me to create an onclick event without doing it inline with the anchor tag? I want to get the ID of the anchor tag clicked, the id is dynamic...

Comment: then you need to append this code with each anchor tag..
`$('#'+json[i].bcid+ json[i].name).click(function() {
 //your code here
});`

Comment: it's not gonna work since i'm doing a chrome packaged app, i will be violating CSP, and if i sandbox the iframe or the page, there will be more issues with CSP

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    VideoDiv(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This will not work because of the nature of `<a>` tag being dynamically generated and the event doesn't get registered. Consider delegating the event (see [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more information):

```
jQuery(document).on("click", 'a', function() {
    VideoDiv(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The above code works, but will delegate for all the `<a>` inside the document. Instead, add a class or something that uniquely identifies that. And call it this way:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", 'a.class', function() {
    VideoDiv(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Another thing about the above delegation of code is, it is better to use a **closest static parent** instead of `document`. Since I don't know the HTML structure, I have used `document`. `:)`

Also, as [Ismael Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2729937/ismael-miguel) says, it is better to get the `id` using `this.id`:

```
jQuery(".static-parent").on("click", '.class', function () {
    VideoDiv(this.id);
});
```

The above would be the best code.

Also, it has been pointed out again, for better performance, you may replace the code with:

```
setTimeout(
  (function () {
    VideoDiv(this.id);
  }).bind(this), 10
);
```

This will let jQuery handle the next even handler, and will execute this code on the next 10ms (when available).

Comment: Don't do that!!! Just do `this.id`. Please! Don't waste processing time and disk space to fetch a single `id`. Please! Just because jQuery is available, doesn't mean you have to use it all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much! We all will apreciate that little advice. To make it **sligtly** better, without many beneficts, one can use `setTimeout((function(){VideoDiv(this.id);}).bind(this),10);`. This will let jQuery handle the next even handler, and will execute this code on the next 10ms (when available).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't understand. What does `setTimeout` do?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I trust you and added it. Thanks! :)

Comment: hey guys i need help here, my onclick still not triggering.. what the hell is wrong with me code OR ME! HAHA

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Wait a min, the context of `this` will be the `window` there right?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan Don't worry buddy. Just create a fiddle in http://jsbin.com and we'll be happy to see what's the problem. `:)`

Comment: `setTimeout` will delay the execution of a certain code for *n* milliseconds. It will be placed in a queue. After those *n* milliseconds, the code will execute when possible. And no, the `this` will be the `this` object in `.bind(this)`. Try this: `(function(){console.log(this);}).bind({})()`.

Comment: I learned it a short time ago. Remember, the trick I showed you will be more useful if `VideoDiv()` is a slow function and takes a long time to complete. It lets jQuery take care of all other event handlers (to change the background, for example) and only then it will run `VideoDiv()`. This prevents the browser from getting locked.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Man, you are awesome. Thanks. I learnt something new. `:)`

Comment: man i can't make the fiddle, coz if i do, it's like i showed you the information just to get in through the site -_- i'm really really sorry, but im glad that you guys, taught each other something new, haha

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can put onclick call to `a` tag while creating it and pass `this` object which is nothing but the `a` tag element, see below code

```
 var htmlCode = '<a href="#/app/video?id='+json[i].bcid+json[i].name+'" class="list" id="'+ json[i].bcid +'" onclick="VideoDiv(this)"></a>';
```

Now make following changes in your javascript function

```
function VideoDiv(anchor)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'thisisprivate.aspx',
            data: {
                action: 'actionNameHere',
                idorname: anchor.id //pass id here from anchor object
            }
        });
}
```

**NOTE**:  your data attribute in above ajax call is incomplete, please correct it.

Comment: Ah man, small error. Do you wanna correct or shall I correct it?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan Looks like there's an error in the code buddy.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, are you talking about data in ajax call ? If yes, then I have put note in my answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: yes it's incomplete here, but it's complete in my document, just as i said in the post, i didn't post the complete code since i'm just pointing out my problem :)

Comment: hmm, the click on my <a> tag still didn't work.. i'll try the other solution but thanks a lot for very fast reply sir @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: have you put onclick call in your anchor tag as I suggested in my answer? Is there any console error on browser?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan You need to delegate the event. Try my answer and let me know. :)

Comment: Yes i placed the onclick call in my anchor tag, wait i'll check again in the console

Comment: so i tried it again, but there's no error on the console except for the font i'm calling my html.. :/

Comment: share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement so that we can help you better

Comment: man i can't make the fiddle, coz if i do, it's like i showed you the information just to get in through the site -_- i'm really really sorry

Comment: then I would suggest to do investigation of the code and find the root cause. Try with some simple javascript function and call it from anchor tag.

Comment: oh ... I did not know if semi colon is mandatory ... anyways good to know that you got the solution

Comment: hmm sorry to bring this back, is there a way for me to create an onclick event without doing it inline with the anchor tag? I want to get the ID of the anchor tag clicked, the id is dynamic...